# How to use a while loop instead of switch case statement to allow for variable number of questions

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, while-loop, switch-statement

I am currently working on developing a "quiz" program in C# and I want to make the number of questions it asks variable so it can be easily changed in the future. Previously, I used a switch case statement to run a series of 20 questions, and the code in each statement is virtually same except for the parameters for which values I pull from MySQL. However, when I try to do the same thing in a while loop, the quiz window does not pop up. This is built on Visual Studio 2019 using the Web Quiz .NET template. Please take a look at the screenshots and let me know if you see any errors that could be causing the quiz to not show up in the while loop but does show up in the switch case. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM2Qd.png) Also, here is [What pops up when I use the switch case but doesnt with the while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZxhL.png). My code:

```
 private void askQuestion(int qnum)
    {
        int numOfRows = 20;
        int questionNum = qnum;
        while (questionNum <= numOfRows)
        {
            string num = "'" + qnum.ToString() + "'";
            lblQuestion.Text = getValue("question", "quizquestions", "questionid", num, "questionid", num);
            //lblQuestion.Text = "An alarm may be canceled by calling the monitoring station and giving them the correct passcode and / or password.";

            button1.Text = getValue("answertext", "answertable", "answerid", "'1'", "questionid", num);
            button2.Text = getValue("answertext", "answertable", "answerid", "'2'", "questionid", num);
            button3.Text = getValue("answertext", "answertable", "answerid", "'3'", "questionid", num); ;
            button4.Text = getValue("answertext", "answertable", "answerid", "'4'", "questionid", num); ;

            scoreBox.Text = "Current Score: " + score + "/20";
            currentQ.Text = "Current Question: " + questionNumber;

            correctAnswer = Int32.Parse(getValue("correctid", "quizanswers", "questionid", num, "questionid", num));

            questionNum++;
        }
    }
    
    /*private void askQuestion(int qnum)
    {
        
        switch (qnum)
        {
            case 1:
                //pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.questions;


                lblQuestion.Text = getValue("question", "quizquestions", "questionid", "'1'", "questionid", "1");
                //lblQuestion.Text = "An alarm may be canceled by calling the monitoring station and giving them the correct passcode and / or password.";

                button1.Text = getValue("answertext", "answertable", "answerid", "'1'", "questionid", "'1'");
                button2.Text = getValue("answertext", "answertable", "answerid", "'2'", "questionid", "'1'");
                button3.Visible = false;
                button3.Text = "";
                button4.Visible = false;
                button4.Text = "";

                scoreBox.Text = "Current Score: " + score +"/20";
                currentQ.Text = "Current Question: " + questionNumber;

                correctAnswer = Int32.Parse(getValue("correctid", "quizanswers", "questionid", "'1'", "questionid", "'1'")); 

                break;
            case 2:...
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `getValue(...)`, as well as any error messages you got?

Comment: Please take a look at my recent 'answer' for the getValue code @MichaelSohnen

Comment: Ok, but be careful with `numOfRows`, the hardcoded value may get you into trouble. Try something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable ...`. Finally, the `qnum` argument seems confusing, since you also have the `while` loop.  You set a variable `questionNum` to `qnum` but then you don't use it.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen I use `questionNum` to increment the while loop and numOfRows will be changed to use sql values, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string getValue(string columnName, string tableName, string refName, string refValue, string ref2Name, string ref2Value)
    {
        string serverIp = "localhost";
        string username = "root";
        string password = "Shared1203";
        string databaseName = "faquiz";

        string value = "";

        string dbConnectionString = string.Format("server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3};", serverIp, username, password, databaseName);
        string query = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + refName + " = " + refValue + " AND " + ref2Name + " = " + ref2Value;

        var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var someValue = reader[columnName];

            value = someValue.ToString();
        }

        return value;
    }
```

No errors received